# Why do $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=2$ and $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=4$ have the same positive root $\sqrt 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-towers

> What is  $x$ when is satisfies $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=2$ ?

I am really confused with this; the root is $\sqrt{2}$, but why does the equation $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=4$ have the same root?

Comment: Why does \udots not work? How can I write dots going from bottom left to top right?

Comment: "How much" is not exactly correct wording in this case

Comment: `{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}` gives e.g. $ x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}} $

Comment: It's clearly a convergence issue, I believe its known that this tower only converges in a certain interval containing $2$ but not $4$. Something with $\exp(1/e)$ and $\exp(e)$ if I remember correctly. Hopefully someone more knowledgable will remember it exactly.

Comment: Interesting enough the maximum $y$ may be for there to be a solution is $e$.

Comment: Apparently variations on this question have been asked many times: [like here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/89375/5189) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87870/5189)

Comment: The true question is: why do you believe that $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=4$ has the same positive root? If you can clarify this, we shall be able to answer your question too.

Comment: Some intuition to why there is an extraneous solution:  $x^{1/x}$ cannot be considered a function on the interval $x \in (a, \infty)$ but can be considered a function for $x \in (a,e)$.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that the two equations have the same root. In fact an equation on the form $f(x)=a$ can not have the same root as $f(x)=b$ if $a\ne b$ because if $x_0$ is the the root of the former then $f(x_0)=a\ne b$ so it's **not** a root of the later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's first start with defining what we mean by the expression $a = x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}$: the infinite [power tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) is the limit of the recursion

$$a_{n+1} = x^{a_n},~~~~~~~ a_0 = x$$

If $x>1$ then $x^x > x$ so $a_{n}$ is monotonically increasing and converges iff it's bounded above (this is the case only if $e^{-e} \leq x \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}\approx 1.44$; see e.g. [Wiki:Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)).  If $x=\sqrt{2}$ then it follows by induction that $a_n \leq 2$ since $a_0 = \sqrt{2} < 2$ and

$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2}^{a_n} \leq \sqrt{2}^2 = 2$$

Thus $a_n$ is bounded above by $2$ (and the recursion therefore converges). Taking the limit of the recursion we get that it satsify the equation $a=x^a$. As you have noted this equation has the two solutions $a=2$ and $a=4$ (which are also the only real solutions). Since the limit is well defined only one of these two solutions are valid and since $a\leq 2$ we have that the solution $a=4$ does not describe the limit of the recursion above.

Why is there an extra solution? Note that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a \implies a = x^a$$

is a one way implication and it's not true that $a = x^a \implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. This is similar to

$$x=1 \implies x^2 = 1 \implies x = \pm 1$$

In this simple example it's squaring that introduces an extra solution. This happens quite a lot when manipulating equations: if not all of the steps are two-way implications then we might introduce extra solutions and we must use some other means to determine which one is the right one to choose.

---

In general when the infinite tower converges the limit is given by

$$a = -\frac{W(-\log(x))}{\log(x)}$$

where $W$ is the (principal branch of the) [Lambert function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). The maximum value (for $x$ where it converges) is found for $x = e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ where we have $a = e < 4$. Thus $x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}} = 4$ has no solutions at all in real numbers so the manipulations you do to get $x = \sqrt{2}$ are not justified.

Answer (score 2):

*(I've answered this at an earlier similar question, see the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87879/1714) , the following is a copy&paste from there)*

---

Also you should consider, whether you would better like to write $\small x$, $\small _bx $ , 
 $\small  _{_b}{_b}x  $ ,$\small  {_{...} }  _{_b}{_b}x  $ , because you always begin the evaluation at the top of the powertower and not at the bottom. And also then it is unambiguous to discuss $\small 2= 2 $, $\small 2 = _\sqrt22 $ ,  $\small 2= _{_\sqrt2}{_\sqrt2}2  $ and $\small 2= {_{...} }  _{_\sqrt2}{_\sqrt2}2  $ as evaluated from the top. It is then also correct to write $\small 4= 4 $, $\small 4 = _\sqrt24 $ , $\small 4= _{_\sqrt2}{_\sqrt2}4  $ and $\small 4= {_{...} }  _{_\sqrt2}{_\sqrt2}4  $ as a second solution. (This is clearly no standard notation, but I really do not know *why* this did not become standard)

[added] Then one could also write $\small 2= \lim {_{...} }  _{_\sqrt2}{_\sqrt2}x  \text{ for } -\infty \lt x \lt 4$ to note the convergence of all that initial values *x*, and because $\small x=\sqrt2 $ is in that range we can say $\small 2= \lim {_{...} }  _{_\sqrt2}{_\sqrt2}\sqrt2  $

---

*[not in the original answer:]* The same occurs also for each of the infinitely many (complex) *fixpoints* of the equation $ \sqrt{2}^{z_k}=z_k$
For instance $z_2 \approx \small 0.145108802639 - 0.220160521524 î $ is such a complex fixpoint in a sense because it fits $z_2 = \exp (  (\log(b)-2 \pi î) \cdot z_2)$ where $b=\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the limit exists, then since $$x^{x^{x^{\cdots }}} = 2$$ then it follows that $$x^2 = 2$$ which has two solutions: $x = \sqrt{2} $ and $x = -\sqrt{2}$. If you're working over the reals, then you'll want to ignore $-\sqrt{2}$.

Do note that all this operates under the assumption that the limit exists, you need to prove it does before the working above is valid.

Comment: Despite all the upvotes, this is not what the OP asked for. He already knows these solutions, he asks why they are the same when the right-hand side is $4$ instead of $2$. I always find it ridiculous when people vote without reading.