# Solving $x^\frac{1}{x}=y$ for $x$

Tags: exponentiation

I've tried everything: Taking $\ln$ of both sides, raising to the power $x$, nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to solve this or am I going to have to use numerical methods instead?

Comment: Elementary application of the lambert w function.

Comment: You might want to look into the [Lambert $W$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) Some manipulation will put your equation into the requisite form. The Lambert $W$-function cannot be expressed in closed form in terms of the usual elementary functions. Some mathematics packages, for example *Maple*, have it routinely available to compute with.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I thought there might be a way to do without the product log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the substitiution $x=e^t$

Then you have

$$(e^t)^{e^{-t}}=y \iff \ln((e^t)^{e^{-t}})=\ln(y) \iff e^{-t} t=\ln(y)$$

Set $t=-z$ then

$$z\cdot e^z = -\ln(y)$$

Now per definition of the [Lambert W Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

$$z=W(-\ln(y)) \iff t = -W(-\ln(y))$$

Therefore your solution is

$$x=e^t=e^{-W(-\ln(y))}=\frac{-W(-\ln(y)}{\ln(y)}$$

(the last equality comes from the wikipedia article)

Comment: Thanks! I was solving that equation because it yields the solution to the infinite power tower problem: Given a number, raise it to the power of itself infinite times. I guess the only good ways are numerical.

Comment: I see, that is example 3 in the wikipedia article. It yields the same result :)

Comment: @itdoesntwork: I presume you haven't seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87870)...

Comment: Listing, demonstrating the last equivalence is easy. You know that $W(t)\exp(W(t))=t$, so $\exp(W(t))=t/W(t)$. Reciprocate both sides and there you go. Having said that, the form that contains the exponential is a bit more useful, as $W(t)/t$ has an unnecessary removable singularity...

Answer (score 0):

Natural log: $\ln(x^{1/x})=\ln(y)$ so that $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\ln(y)$. That's as far as you can get in terms of elementary functions. To finish solving you need something like the "product log" function as mentioned by Wolfram Alpha as it [solves the equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E%281/x%29=y%20for%20x).

Comment: Yeah I know about the product log function. I knew it would go into that at some point, so I asked here for anything else :) Thanks!