# Largest $x$ such that the power tower (tetration) $x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, tetration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Infinite tetration, convergence radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius)

Recently in this thread, [Pseudo Proofs that are intuitively reasonable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123633/pseudo-proofs-that-are-intuitively-reasonable), I learned that 
$$\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{...}}}} = 2$$

The next natural question to ask is, what is the largest number $x$ such that 
$$f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$$
converges?

A short exercise in matlab coding suggests that either $f(1.5)$ diverges, or whatever it converges to is too large for my computer to handle. Thus the answer should be somewhere between 1.41 and 1.5.

Comment: It is not explicitly mentioned on the linked question, but the radius of convergence you are looking for is $e^{1/e} = \max_y y^{1/y} \approx 1.4446678$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer TMM. Sorry to ask a duplicate question - I searched for "power tower" before asking, but did not know of the term "tetration".

Comment: your expression could be reduced to an infinite product of (1/2)ln(x). Now use the infinite product convergence theorems and try compute rhs. sorry i am int rush to get to work would try post more details later.