# Solving $4=2^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}} $ for $ x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve the following equal for $x$?

$$4=2^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$$

I'm bit confused, how do you even simplify this equation, factoring?

Comment: If $x^{x^{x^{x^{x^\cdots}}}}=y, x^y=y$ Now, how to find $y?$

Comment: If there is a solution, x^x^x^... must be 2, so 2=x^x^x^...=x^(x^x^...)=x^2, so $x=\sqrt2$. The hard thing is to show that there is a solution (if there are no solutions, the above is just nonsense, like all those false proofs of 0=1).

Comment: is it possible to prove it then?

Comment: Yes, the key word is *tetration*. You may want to read this [article](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=3087&pf=1). See also this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/108288/462). The article is linked in the solution given there.

Comment: Before solving this equation (formally, like everyone did), you have to define the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

First let us notice that $2 = x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}$ (since $4=2^2$). Now we can see that $\log_x 2 = x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}} = 2 \implies \log_x 2 = 2 \implies 2 = x^2 \iff x = \pm \sqrt{2}$ however we can run into issues if we use the negative square root so we take $x = + \sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$4=2^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$$
let ${x^{x^{x^{...}}}}=y\implies x^y=y$
$$4=2^y$$
$$2^2=2^y$$
$$y=2$$
$$x^y=y$$
$$x^2=2$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt2$$

Comment: this doesn't seem to solve for $x$ as asked...

Comment: $\log_{2}4 = 2$. I don't think that this solution gets you much closer to solving the problem.

Comment: @AWertheim well it gets closer (somewhat) but you could just notice that $4=2^2$ so it must be true that $2 = x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}$

Comment: @DanZimm certainly, I don't mean to seem uncharitable, just that (as you note) it doesn't seem to be a particularly illuminating observation. This is just my opinion though.