# When does $x^{x^{x^{...}}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Provided that $x$ is positive, when does the following converge? $$x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$$

> I just had a talk with my friend who is taking a calculus class and he is dealing a lot with divergence and convergence stuff. His TA said that if anyone could answer this and write a proof, he or she doesn't have to come to the recitation class anymore. This drives me a lot.

So here is my work, but I don't really know if this is correct. Could anyone shed some light on this?

> I haven't done any real analysis before so I'm trying to make use of
>   whatever I can use, and my plan is to find the critical points of $y'$
>   and look at the graph of $y=f(x)$. First let
>   $f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}=y=x^y$, then I have $$ \ln{y}=y\ln{x} $$ $$
>  \frac{d(\frac{\ln{y}}{y})}{dx} = \frac{d\ln{x}}{dx} $$ $$
>  \frac{1-\ln{y}}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$ $$ y'=
>  \frac{f^2(x)}{x(1-\ln{f(x)})} $$ Now I noticed that the critical
>   points are $x=0$ and $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=e$. Since
>   $f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$ is an increasing function, the graph of
>   $y=f(x)$ would go up vertically at some point as $x$ increases, and that
>   is when the function diverges. From these 3 critical points, $f(x)=e$
>   seems to make most sense. By plugging $f(x)=e$ back into $y=x^y$, it's
>   not hard to see that $f(x)=e$ occurs at $x=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$. So the
>   function converges when $x\in (0, e^{\frac{1}{e}})$

Edit: I just noticed something strange in my proof:
$$ y'= \frac{f^2(x)}{x(1-\ln{f(x)})} $$
When $f(x)>e$, the denominator on the right hand side is negative. But since $f(x)$ is an increasing function, therefore, shouldn't $y'$ be positive? Now it seems to deep for me to perceive...

Comment: Why should $f$ be differentiable in the first place?

Comment: You may wish to see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius?rq=1).

Comment: The upper bound is correct. For the lower, try $e^{-e}$

Comment: I always like to phrase the question as:

Solve $x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}} = 4$.

Now solve $x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}} = 2$.

Comment: Why $0<x<e^{-e}$ doesn't make the function converge? I ask this because it seems to me that this should converge just by inspection.

Comment: Inspection.  What a great (but phony) reason.

Comment: It does indeed even converge for $(0,e^{\frac{1}{e}}]$. Your proof is not very rigorous anyway (differentiability,...). Better proof: define $x_{n+1}=x^{x_n}$, then proof by induction that $x_n \leq e$ for $x \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}} $

Comment: @JulianBraun It does not converge there. The sequence should be $a_{n+1} = a_{n} ^{x}$ with $a_{0} = x$. With $x \in (0, e^{-e})$ the series alternates, $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ converge to different values.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), it converges for $e^{-e}\le x\le e^{1/e}$. This was proven by Euler.

Comment: @kalhartt you really need to define it like I already did above. $(x^x)^x = x^{(x \cdot x)}$! But Akiva is right with the convergence interval. I actually meant $[1,e^{\frac{1}{e}}]$, this is where the $x_n$ are just monotone increasing and bounded.

Comment: @JulianBraun Yes, I mistakenly swapped $a_n$ and $x$ on the rhs above. My point is that the lower bound is not 0 or 1 but $e^{-e}$ inclusive and that boundedness is not enough to show convergence here. Also using $x_n$ as a symbol for the finite tetration can be confusing when $x$ is already used as a single value.