# Evaluating $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\:^{.^{\:^{.^{\: \infty}}}}}}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to evaluate $$\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\:^{.^{\:^{.^{\: \infty}}}}}}}$$

Let $$x^{x^{x^{x^{\;^{\cdots{^\infty}}}}}}=2$$ Then $x^2=2 \implies x=\sqrt2$

Now 
Let $$x^{x^{x^{\:^{.^{\:^{{. ^\infty}}}}}}}=4$$ Then $x^4=4\implies x=\sqrt2$. So I am getting the two values $2$ and $4$ for $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\:^{.^{\:^{.^{\: \infty}}}}}}}$

where is the ambiguity ?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I don't think this is a duplicate (at least not of the question you linked to).  The OP here is asking about an apparent paradox.

Comment: @BarryCipra Ah, you are likely right, my bad!

Comment: Perhaps this will be a better duplicate, explaining why it is not possible for the power tower to equal $4$: [Infinite tetration, convergence radius](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each case, you are *tacitly assuming* that a (positive) real number $x$ exists such that the sequence $x_0=1$, $x_{n+1}=x^{x_n}$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, has a given limit (namely $2$ in the first case and $4$ in the second).  That tacit assumption may or may not be valid *in either case*.  What you've shown is that it cannot be valid in *both* cases.

As for the limit (if any...) of the sequence with $x=\sqrt2$, note first that $x_0=1\lt\sqrt2=x_1$, from which we find that $x_{n-1}\lt x_n$ implies $x_n=\sqrt2^{x_{n-1}}\lt\sqrt2^{x_n}=x_{n+1}$ for all $n$, so that the sequence is monotonically increasing (and strictly positive).  Note second that $x_0=1\lt2$, from which it follows that $x_{n-1}\lt2$ implies $x_n=\sqrt2^{x_{n-1}}\lt\sqrt2^2=2$ for all $n$, so the sequence is bounded above (by $2$).  Together these imply the sequence with $x=\sqrt2$ has a positive limit, and that limit is less than or equal to $2$.

If we now let $L$ denote that limit, then we can conclude that $L=\sqrt2^L$, or $L^2=2^L$ (with $L\ge0$).  By graphing the parabola $y=L^2$ and the exponential curve $y=2^L$, it's easy to see that the only non-negative solutions to $L^2=2^L$ are $L=2$ and $L=4$.  But we already know that $L\le2$.  Hence the limit of the sequence with $x=\sqrt2$ is $2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer☺the method in your answer can be easily generalised to any value of x.