# $p_0 = 1,~~p_i = c^{p_{i−1}} . $ Find the largest $c$ such that this sequence is bounded.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

For a given $c$ define the power tower $p$ of $c$ as follows: $$p_0 = 1,~~p_i = c^{p_{i−1}} . $$ Find the largest $c$ such that this sequence is bounded.

Clearly $c=1$ works. So assumer $c>1.$
Note that for $c>1,$ $c^n$ is increasing as $n$ increases.

There are two cases:

1. There exists $x\ge 1$ such that $c^x\le x$
2. There does not exist $x\ge 1$ such that $c^x\le x$

Note that if there exists $x\ge 1$ such that $c^x\le x$ and hence we get the sequence $\{c^n\}$ to be bounded above by $x.$ Since $\{c^n\}$ is bounded above then so is $\{p_i\}.$

But I couldn't understand the following part.

[image]

[image]

After this we have to find the maximum value of $c$ such that there exist $x$ such that $c^x\le x\implies x^{1/x}\le c$ or find maximum value of $c$ which is ( after differentiating) we get $e^{1/e}.$

My doubt is, I get that $c^x-x$ is increasing but it might be bounded above so how can we say that there exists $A$ such that $c^A>A+c-1$  ( we know that $c^x>x$ for all $x>1$).

Moreover, if $c^x-x$ is increasing, then in the interval $[1,A]$ wouldn't $c-1$ be the minimum?

And lastly, I did not understand how $p_i=c^{p_{i-1}}\ge p_{i-1}+m.$ But I understood that if $p_i=c^{p_{i-1}}\ge p_{i-1}+m$, then we must have $p_i\ge 1+m\cdot i.$

Any help or other solution is appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius) and let me know if it eventually answers this question. If your question is primarily about the argument you're reading, then this is not going to answer your question, of course.

Comment: You have assumed $c>1$, which means the expression won't be bounded above.

Comment: @TravorLZH . You are mistaken. If $1<d\le e$ and $c=d^{1/d}$ then the series converges to $d$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm saying that $c^x-x$ will be unbounded automatically if $c>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly writing few terms

$$1, c, c^c , c^{c^c}, c^{c^{c^c}}, \ldots$$

$c=1$ satisfies the boundedness condition. To find better solution let us assume $c>1$. Also, let $t_n$ is the $n$th term of the sequence.

Let the limit of the sequence is denoted by $x$, i.e. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = x$$ Therefore, $$c^x-x =0$$ because $c>0$.

We want to find the largest $c$ which satisfies this condition. From the equation above

$$ \frac{1}{c} \frac{dc}{d x} =\frac{\log(x) -1}{\log(x)^2}$$

Solving to $x=e$ and $c = e^{1/e}$

p.s.: Edited my completely wrong answer.

Comment: This can not be true since $c=e^{1/e}$ is the answer and $c>1$