# Find $x$: $x^{x^x ...} = 2$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am given the equation $x^{x^x ...} = 2$ where the power of $x$ goes on infinitely. Assuming this holds for some $x$, it follows that $x^2 = 2$. Therefore, $x = \sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$. In the book I am reading, the author only states $x = \sqrt{2}$ as the solution. How can I rule out the other option  $x = -\sqrt{2}$? any input very appreciated!

Comment: We run into deep trouble already with $x^x$ , if $x$ is negative irrational. The range in which the power tower converges is mentioned in many posts here on this site.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius

Comment: $x = -\sqrt{2}$ *is* a valid solution if you allow for complex-valued logarithms.

Comment: Remember that $A \implies B$ does *not* mean that $B\implies A$.  After all $x = 5 \implies (x-7)^2 = 4$ does not mean that $(x-7)^2 = 4\implies x = 5$.  We have $x^{x^{x^{...}}} =2\implies x^2 =2$ but $x^2 =2\not \implies x^{x^{x^{...}}} =2$.  A negative number can not be raised to an irrational power so $-\sqrt 2$ as a solution is off the table.... Actuallly we have to verify that $\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2^{....}}}$ is well defined ant that $\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2^{....}}}$ *does* equal $2$ before we can declare it is the answer. All we know is its the only thing that *could* be answer.

Comment: "... It follows that $x^2 =2$.  Therefore $x = \sqrt 2$ or $-\sqrt 2$".  Not quite.  It follows that if it has any answers at all they must be some $\sqrt 2$ or $-\sqrt 2$.  There are $4$ possibilities 1) both $\sqrt 2$ and $-\sqrt 2$ are answers. 2)$\sqrt 2$ is an answer but $-\sqrt 2$ isn't.  3) $-\sqrt 2$ is an answer but $\sqrt 2$ isn't.  or 4) Neither are answers and there is no answer.  As it turns out 2) is the correct conclusion. "$x$ is the answer"$\implies x^2 =2$ does not mean that $x^2 =2\implies$ "$x$ is the answer".