# Fun math books for 8 year old with math aptitude

Tags: recreational-mathematics

My 8 year old showed interest and aptitude for math well above the level they teach in her school. I would like to find some math books that would spike her interest in math and make it fun for her.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/what-was-the-first-bit-of-mathematics-that-made-you-realize-that-math-is-beautif

Comment: Enroll her in competition program at AoPS

Comment: Ian Stewart has tons of things like that.

Comment: Also, you could possibly contact my dad, he had the exact same problem :-) (This likely applies to the parents of many people here, if I had to guess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*The Number Devil*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805062998), by Hans Magnus Enzensberger, is an absolute gem, and the first review currently displayed at Amazon is remarkably appropriate. It begins:

> I checked this book out of the library to read to my 8 year old daughter (she wanted me to read "Flatland" to her and I thought the dated language might get in the way). She loved it and now I plan to purchase two copies; one for her and one for my 12 year old son. The book jacket decribed the book as a cross between Flatland and Alice's Adventures in Wonderland. I would have described it as a cross between Flatland an[d] The Phantom Tollbooth, but, no matter. It definitely provides food for thought for any reasonably inquisitive child; and may provide more for a child already interested in mathematics.

I have no quarrel with any of this.

Comment: Ah, I remember that! I mean, I was probably also eight-ish, so I don't remember a lot of details, but I remember loving that book.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I was 50 when it came out in English, and I still loved it!

Comment: The "Frequently bought together" section includes _Penrose: The Mathematical Cat_. Oh, god, the memories!

Comment: (Oh, and I must have been at least ten, looking at the publication date)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are very good at math Can you tell more about yourself I really want to know you in person. How old are you now sir?

Comment: @Soheil: Most of what I’m willing to say is in my profile, but I don’t mind adding that I am now $72$ and knew before I was $10$ that I would be a mathematician and a teacher.

Comment: Thank You sir for the answer and giving me the honor to meet you!

Comment: @Soheil: You’re welcome!