# Explaining the joy behind Math to the Common Folk

Tags: soft-question, intuition, education

As a math student, it is hard for me to explain the beauty of math to non-mathematicians. So I wonder, how can one explain the elegance of abstract mathematics to somebody without a special background in math, but who is genuinely interested in understanding the joy that comes with it?

To make this clear: I am not asking about how to present knowledge in an understandable way so that your friend actually knows what a manifold is for the rest of her/his life. It's more about giving a VERY general idea of why some crazy people (called mathematicians) would consider an induction proof *elegant* or even *beautiful*. This should be adressing adults who got through high school, so I suppose more advanced concepts than [those for a children's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/what-was-the-first-bit-of-mathematics-that-made-you-realize-that-math-is-beautif) or [these first cool math experiences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/what-was-the-first-bit-of-mathematics-that-made-you-realize-that-math-is-beautif?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) are desirable. Something that might take an hour to explain but is worth the effort.

What beautiful theorems or ideas do you know of that make sense *intuitively* to non-mathematicians when explained in the right way? Which of them are obviously beautiful, even if one doesn't know all the details about it?

Comment: I like Hall's matching theorem. It's a surprising result, has nothing to do with numbers (which dispels a common misconception) and the argument is very aesthetic.

Comment: Perhaps my logician is showing, but a high level picture of the incompleteness theorems can also be fun. At the level of "you find a way to encode 'this sentence is not provable'. If it's true, it's not provable, and if it's false you can prove false... Both of these are scary"

Comment: For me *integral Apollonian packing*, together with the minimum background, is simply amazing.

Comment: Perhaps this could prove useful to you:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47214/how-to-present-mathematics-to-non-mathematicians

Comment: Since you mentioned induction , I really  like the false proof of showing "every people on earth have the same age" ! by induction .

Comment: It is very difficult to explain this to a non mathematician. There are some theorems and proofs which anyone can understand, but not many people will actually appreciate it.