# Confusion regarding probability of microbe producing everlasting colony.

Tags: probability, problem-solving

My question is about the given solution to problem 4 in Newman's book 'A Problem Seminar'. Note that the book is available online at [Springer](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8214-0/page/1).

**Problem 4**

> A microbe either splits into two perfect copies of itself or else 
>   disintegrates. If the probability of splitting is p, what is the 
>   probability that one microbe will produce an everlasting colony?
>
> **Solution:**
>   We can (almost) solve this problem by expressing the unknown 
>   probability, $x$, in terms of itself. For, after all, how can the one 
>   microbe multiply forever? Only in one way. It must at the first 
>   moment split, and then at least one of its two daughters must 
>   succeed in the task of the mother (i.e., lead to an eternal 
>   progeny). In short $x= p\cdot(1-(1-x)^ 2)$. We can solve for x and 
>   get the answer! ...

From my understanding, $(1-(1-p)^2)$ means the probability of at least one microbe splitting. However, I have no idea why $x= p\cdot(1-(1-x)^ 2)$ instead of $x= p\cdot(1-(1-p)^ 2)$. How does $x$ get into the $(1-x)^2$? What does  $(1-(1-x)^ 2)$ intuitively mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x$ is the probability that a microbe produces an everlasting colony, $1-x$ is the probability that a microbe’s line will die out. Now we start with one microbe; with probability $p$ it splits. The daughter lines survive or die out independently of each other, so the probability that both daughter lines die out is $(1-x)^2$. The probability that at least one daughter line is everlasting is therefore the complementary probability $1-(1-x)^2$.

Thus, the probability that the original microbe splits **and** has at least one everlasting daughter line is $p\big(1-(1-x)^2\big)$. But this is just the probability that the original microbe’s line is everlasting, so $x=p\big(1-(1-x)^2\big)$.

Comment: Great explanation!