# Probability of k out of m microbes splitting.

Tags: probability

A microbe either splits into two perfect copies of itself or else disintegrates. If the probability of splitting is p, what is the probability that there will be m microbes in the nth generation. Furthermore, what is the probability that out of these m microbes, k will split?

So far, I found that the probability that k will split (out of the total of m microbes) is $P=mp^k(1-p)^{m-k}$. I derived this equation by induction (i.e. looking for an equation that agrees with numerical values for small m and k). I am not fully certain that the coefficient m should be there from a formal mathematical point of view, since I think that $P=p^k(1-p)^{m-k}$ makes more intuitive sense (however, the numerical values of P for small m and k are wrong).

How can I combine the probability of k microbes splitting out of m microbes together with the probability of there being m microbes at the nth generation?.

Adapted from Problem 4 in Newman's book, 'A Problem Seminar', available online at [Springer](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8214-0/page/1). 
Related question: [Confusion regarding probability of microbe producing everlasting colony](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407047/confusion-regarding-probability-of-microbe-producing-everlasting-colony).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability should actually be

$$\binom{m}{k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}$$

and is a transition probability, it tells you the probability of having $m+k$ bacteria in the $n+1$th generation given you had $m$ in the $n$th. So, you have a Markov chain with the following master equation:

$$P(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} \binom{m-k}{k} p^k (1-p)^{m-2 k} P(m-k,n-1) \; .$$

Comment: Remark:'the probability of having $m+k$ microbes in the $n+1$th generation given you had $m$ in the $n$th' is equivalent to 'the probability of $k$ microbes splitting and $m-k$ microbes disintegrating in the transition from the $n$th to the $n+1$th generations', because $(m-k)+2k=m+k$

Comment: Why should $m-k$ microbes disintegrate? $m-k$ just don't split, it's the $k$ ones that split that should be counted double so to speak.

Comment: My mistake: I've corrected my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The probability is actually

$$\binom{m}{k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}$$

where

$$\binom{m}{k} = \frac{m!}{k! (m-k)!}$$

assuming each (independent) event (i.e., microbe splitting) is a Bernoulli trial.

Comment: Are you referring to the probability that k out of m microbes will split ?

Comment: @Raindrop: yes I am.  This is widely known as the binomial distribution.