# On the existence/applications of infinitely-nested functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, recurrence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

Inside [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87870/are-the-solutions-of-xxxx-cdot-cdot-cdot-2-correct), one particular nested function shown is the known [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). 
This "kind" of arbitrary repeated functions has always intrigued me, because inside their properties lie so many beautiful relations (i.e. the domain of $\lim_{n\to+\infty}{}^nx$ is $e^{-e}\leq x\leq e^{1/e}$).

So I wanted to define a similar expression, and search for its properties:
$$
f(n,x)={}^n\log x=\underbrace{\log(\log(\log(\ldots\log x)))}_{n\text{ times}},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}^+,x\in\mathbb{R}
%\quad\text{or}\quad{}^n\sin x=\underbrace{\sin(\sin(\sin(\ldots\sin x)))}_{n\text{ times}}
$$
just looking at how the domain explodes even when $n<8$ baffles me, as I obtained:
$$
\mathcal{D}_{f(n\geq2,x)}:x>{}^{n-2}e\wedge\mathcal{D}_{f(1,x)}:x>0\quad\text{for example, }\;\mathcal{D}_{f(7,x)}:x\gtrsim 10^{10^{10^{6.22}}}
$$ 
This may be not the only "strange" property of this particular function, but even if I think it can be exploited, I've never found any source (neither textbooks nor online); so in conclusion, is there any application of such function (or functions' class)?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, it was established by Kevin Ford, Ben Green, Sergei Konyagin, Terence Tao, and also by James Maynard, that there are prime gaps below $N$ as large as $$c\frac{\log N\log\log N\log\log\log\log N}{(\log\log\log N)^2}$$ when $N$ is large enough, and they showed that $c$ could be as large as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Let us examine this.

$^{1}\log(x)$  only yields a real number for positive real $x$. For other $x$, they are never never real.

$^{2}\log(x)$ only yields a real value for real values of $x>1=10^0$ It is undefinied for $x=1$, and has only nonreal values otherwise.

$^{3}\log(x)=\log(^2\log(x))$ Taking the antilog of the inequality above, we can deduce that it only returns a real value for $x>10=10^1$

$^{4}\log(x)=\log(^3\log(x))$ Taking the antilog of the inequality above, we can deduce that it only returns a real value for $x>10^{10}=10^{10^1}$

Note that for each increase of $n$ by 1, the minimum value for $x$ for a real result is the common antilog of the minimum value  the the previous.

$$^{n}\log(x)=log(^{n-1}log(x))$$ The minimum value of $x$ for this to be a real number is equal to taking the common antilog of 1 $n-2$ times.