# How can I solve this equation $x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-a=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, tetration

I always use the Newton-Raphson Method if I want to find the roots of any equation as follow
$$x_{1}=x_{0}-\frac{y_{0}}{y'_{0}}$$

But I don't know how to use this method if the equation takes the following form 
$$x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-a=0$$

where $a=$ positive number

I know some solved cases when $a=2$ so that the $x=\sqrt 2$

Now I want to find the solution when $a=e$

Comment: Check Lambert w function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the solutions of $x^{x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{{\cdot}^{\cdot}}}}}}=2$ correct?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87870/are-the-solutions-of-xxxx-cdot-cdot-cdot-2-correct)

Comment: My question is numerically

Comment: Here is a good [example 3](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have $x^a=a$ and hence $x=a^{1/a}$. It converges for all [$a\in[e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights).

Comment: Perhaps it is of interest to do the generalization to complex numbers. Then your mentioned interval becomes a region of convergence called "Shell-Thron-region" (see wikipedia)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we assume that $x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$ converges...
lets us define a series $a_n$  
$a_0 = x$ 
$a_{n+1} = x^{a_n}$

also we know that series limit is $a$, $a_n\rightarrow a$,
 therefore:
 
$a=x^a$
$\ln(a)=a\ln(x)$
$\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(a)}{a}=\ln(a^{\frac{1}{a}})$
$x=a^{\frac{1}{a}}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}-a &=0 \\
x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}} &=a \\
x^a&=a \\
a\log_a x &= 1\\
\log_a x &= \frac{1}{a}\\
x &=a^\frac{1}{a} \\
\end{align}$$

---

Note that this only works for $a\leq e$, because $a^\frac{1}{a}$ is not a unique-valued function.

Comment: $x^a = a$ is a necessary condition but is it sufficient?