# Square rooting in tetration.

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, tetration

I have been interested in tetration for a while and I have this question: what is the tetration-root of $2$? ($x^x=2$). In tetration form, it can be written as 2^^x. In general, I am just curious on how to find the tetration-root of any number. i.e. $x^x=a$.
Is there is an infinite formula, product, or Taylor series for this type of equation?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5Ex%3D2

Answer (score 1):

$x \approx1.55961046946236935$ has $x^x =2$.

You could say $x = e^{W(\log_e 2)}$, where $W()$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) with $w=W(z)$ when $we^w=z$

For $x^x = a$,

- when $a >1$ you can replace the $2$ with $a$ so $x = e^{W(\log_e a)}$
- when $e^{-1/e} \lt a \le 1$ there are two non-negative real roots corresponding to the two branches of the Lambert W function
- when $a= e^{-1/e}$ there is one root, namely $x=e^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

There also exist higher super square roots. Simply go that section in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).
In general, on can solve for $x^x=y$ for y using what is called the “super square root:
$$\mathrm{y=x^x\implies x=\sqrt{y}_s=ssrt(y)=e^{W(ln(x))}=\frac{ln(x)}{W(ln(x))}}$$

where W(x) is the [Product Logarithm](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/), W-Lambert, Function.

Replace the index of the implied 2 in the surd part with n and you will get the made up inverse of the other function.

It can also be noted that:
$$\mathrm{x^{x^…}=y\implies x=y^{1/y}=\sqrt[\infty]{y}_s}$$

This means that the answer of inserting y=2 has, like another answer said. The answer of: $$\mathrm{\mathrm{y=x^x\implies x=\sqrt{2}_s=ssrt(2)=e^{W(ln(2))}=\frac{ln(2)}{W(ln(2))}}= 1.55961046946236934997038876876500299328488351184309142=a...\implies a^a=2}$$

Also, here is a [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iqzxlvxlsp) answer to see this graphically:[image]

However, there also exist other solutions using different branches of the predefined W(x) function with the link. [Software](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%3D2) is better explaining than I am. Here are the other solutions with the [other branches](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/) as its inverse is a relation unless modified.

Comment: What about ${^{x}x}=2$

Comment: @max if you mean $$\underbrace{x^{x^…}}_x=2$$, then $x=\sqrt 2$. See [here for a similar example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969038/powertower-with-sqrt2).

Comment: I thought that is only true for an infinite power tower.

Comment: @Max [See answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261689/is-there-a-way-to-write-the-n-textth-super-root-in-terms-of-the-lambert-w-f) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314712/calculating-the-nth-super-root-when-n-is-greater-than-2). There is no closed form, except for a few special cases. Also, the super root is not very common in math, so I am not sure if it is a closed form. [*Tetration forum*](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/)

Comment: This is an answer with an outdated writing style