# How do I solve the equation $2^x - x^2 = 0$, using logarithms with base 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I solve the  equation $2^x - x^2 = 0$ for $x$ by using pen and paper?
By rearranging the terms and taking $\log_2$ on both sides I obtain $x - \log_2 x^2  = 0.$

By using graphical calculator I know that there are three solutions. How do I proceed from the second equation to obtain these solutions? Maybe I am missing some trick here?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ is not a solution. There is no algebraic solution using the usual operations.

Comment: There is no direct way to calculate the solutions (if they cannot be guessed). We need numercial methods or the Lambert-W function might allow a closed form solution.

Comment: To emphasize, there are many questions which might be easy to ask but which are difficult to answer.  Mixing exponentials and polynomials is exactly one such scenario.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ is not a solution, that was my bad.

Comment: How about $x=2,4$?

Comment: The third solution (apart from $2$ and $4$) is $$-0.7666646959621230931112\cdots $$

Comment: One way to solve for $x=2,4$ is:

$x=\sqrt2\,^x\implies x=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt2^x}$ and iterate. Then use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87870/are-these-solutions-of-2-xxx-cdot-cdot-cdot-correct/87897#87897)

Comment: The solutions are 2, 4 and -0.766... I naively assumed that there was a  direct way to calculate the solutions. But apparantly one must use  numerical methohds or as Peter, Ichoi and Abezhiko suggested by  using Lambert W function. Thanks for the answers : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pen and paper, there is not much to do analytically apart from using the Lambert W function; it would go that way :
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
x^2 = 2^x = e^{x\ln 2} &\Longleftrightarrow& x^2e^{-x\ln 2} = 1 \\
                       &\Longleftrightarrow& xe^{-x\ln\sqrt{2}} = \pm 1 \\
                       &\Longleftrightarrow& (-x\ln\sqrt{2})e^{-x\ln\sqrt{2}} = \pm \ln\sqrt{2} \\
                       &\Longleftrightarrow& x_k^\pm = \displaystyle \frac{W_k(\pm\ln\sqrt{2})}{-\ln\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
$$
where $k$ denotes the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ branch of the Lambert W function. Otherwise, graphical methods are helpful, as mentioned by lChoi.

Answer (score 1):

These equations aren't usually soluble with a standard method. I think for this equation, one must graph the two graphs $2^x$ and $x^2$ and bound the solutions first (as $x$ can't be that big, as $2^x$ grows much quicker than $x^2$), and then guess at them. We can then make sure we're not missing any solutions then by looking at the graphs again.

Comment: Look at graphs "and then guess them"??

Comment: Yes - by looking at the graph you could ascertain how many solutions there are, and their rough size. Guessing and then verifying would be a valid strategy here.